# Fun experiment on memory: for data of one subject (myself), is there a name for it?

Tags: terminology

I'm doing a year experiment on memory and I'm the only subject. I will be done collecting data in 2 months. I've been using software to evaluate myself daily as I collect data.

Is there a name in the literature for such kind of experiments where you evaluate yourself?

(NOTE: I won't publish my results, it's only for fun and to have an educated guess of my progress in memorizing).

Answer (score 4):

> **Self-experimentation** refers to the special case of single-subject research in which the experimenter conducts the experiment on himself or herself.

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-experimentation))